# How to reinitialise the very same thread in android?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm using GCM to receive message from google server. when the message has received at device ; it starts a 1-minute thread, and if no other message has come until 1min it will show the analog clock on screen. but if before 1 minute the message has come: here's the problem how can reinitialise the thread from zero to measure again 1min???

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                analogClock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lblMessage.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
});

t.start ();
// Schedule task to terminate thread in 1 minute 
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.schedule ( 
    new Runnable(){
   @Override
       public void run (){
        t.interrupt();
      }
    } , 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: design your runnable task to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you really can't *reuse* threads (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324030/java-thread-reuse)). Just create another one.

To cancel previous task you can cancel the `ScheduledFuture` using [`cancel(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29):

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = exec.schedule ( 
    new Runnable(){
   @Override
       public void run (){
        t.interrupt();
      }
    } , 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
...
future.cancel(true); // Or false, I don't know your exact requirements here
```

Anyway in your case and in Android you're better off with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of `Thread`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add more detail on how to cancel previous scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution seems to be to keep a rest boolean in the thread - when you scheduled runnable executes you can either terminate the thread or reschedule this runnable for a new minute in the future.

You can't exactly reuse a thread in Java but you can plan NOT to terminate your thread unless it is appropriate.

Comment: How to use logic with boolean to made it again reschedule for 1 min? any code snippet would help!!! make sure need to reschedule on every new message received.