# Java - Runnable confusion

Tags: java

As I have already mentioned I am pretty new to programming world.
I am currently facing a problem with runable. When I am checking the status of boolean shutdown the code is running all the time, instead of expected every 30 seconds.
My code so far:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestClass {
static boolean shutdown;


public static void main(String[] args) {


    notify(30);
}

private static void notify(int num) {

    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(!shutdown){
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, num, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

}
```

**Edit:** I need somehow to stop the method from running, that's why I have used boolean shutdown.

Comment: Remove the while-loop.

Comment: @beatngu13 Actually I do need the while loop, because I want somehow to stop it's execution. So I thought of getting a boolean to control whether it should run or not.

Comment: The executor service will invoke `run()` every 30 seconds, the execution automatically stops when the end of the method is reached. Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @beatngu13 Well, the method actually seems to run in eternity since every 30 seconds a new thread will respawn. I need somehow to stop it -in runtime.

Comment: The executor doesn't spawn a new thread every 30 seconds. You initialized a pool of size 1, that means it has 1 thread that will be reused. After the first invocation of `run()`, this thread runs forever because of the while-loop. Even if you set `shutdown = true`, it might won't stop since the variable isn't `volatile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop is causing the thread to tight spin forever.  I bet your computer is showing 100% core usage when this runs.

`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` returns an `ScheduledFuture<?>` object.  What you need to do is call `cancel()` on it to stop the task from executing.

You need to remove the while loop and cancel the `ScheduledFuture<?>`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

**I typed this into notepad - it probably won't compile but you should get the idea.**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestClass {
static ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
static boolean shutdown = false;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     new ShutdownChecker(30);
     Thread.sleep(90_000);
     shutdown = true;
}

private static class ShutdownChecker implements Runnable
{
    private final ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public ShutdownChecker(int time)
    {
        future = TestClass.exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, num, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if(TestClass.shutdown)
        {
            future.cancel();
            System.out.println("not running");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("running");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a snippet?

Answer (score -1):

ScheduledExecutorService will pass the `Runnable` instance into an available `Thread` from the `ThreadPool` after the period specified.

Comment: I know that, but what I am trying to achieve is to stop it.

Comment: You will need one more Thread to monitor the status of boolean. If your boolean is true, shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: The executor won't spawn a new thread after each period. Read it up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324030/java-thread-reuse).