# Why thread is not in TERMINATED state after thread.join?

Tags: multithreading, scala

I have this code snippet where i check the state of the thread after it is finished.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaSetConverter
import scala.concurrent.duration.{Duration, SECONDS}


object ThreadUsage2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("Main thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName())
    val ex = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    var threadName = ""
    val sleepTask = new Thread(() => {

      threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName()
      println("Executing Thread task :" + Thread.currentThread().getName())
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      println("Thread  finished :" + Thread.currentThread().getName())
    })

    ex.execute(sleepTask)

    sleepTask.join()
    Thread.sleep(10000)

    println("Now the sleep task is in state" + sleepTask.getState)


    val running = Thread.getAllStackTraces.keySet()

    running.asScala.toSet[Thread].foreach(a => {

      if (a.getName.matches(threadName)) {

        println(" thread with name " + threadName + " is in state " + a.getState)

      }
    })

  }
}
```

The output that i see is confusing. I expect the thread to be in state TERMINATED. I see two different states in the two prints in have.
Output:

`Main threadmain
Executing Thread task :scala-execution-context-global-12
Thread  finished :scala-execution-context-global-12
Now the sleep task is in stateNEW
 thread with name scala-execution-context-global-12 is in state TIMED_WAITING`

what is the reason for the above thread states?

Answer (score 2):

@Yaneeve has diagnosed the problem: your `sleepTask` thread is never actually started.

But why does `join` return for  a `Thread` that hasn't been started?

This is explained by the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)).

> This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`.  As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on Thread instances.

Since `isAlive` first becomes `true` when a thread starts, the above means that "joining" a thread that hasn't been started will succeed immediately.  This (kind of) contradicts the previous sentence of the javadoc which states:

> Waits at most `millis` milliseconds for this thread to die.

But clearly, this is the way that the implementation behaves ...

Answer (score 1):

`execute` receives a `Runnable`:

```
/** Runs a block of code on this execution context.
 *
 *  @param runnable  the task to execute
 */
def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit
```

Thus the executor only cares about the code block that you had supplied as:

```
   () => {
          threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName()
          println("Executing Thread task :" + Thread.currentThread().getName())
          Thread.sleep(5000)
          println("Thread  finished :" + Thread.currentThread().getName())
        }
```

That is since `Thread` *is a* `Runnable`

```
class Thread implements Runnable
```

Therefore the `sleepTask.join()` is immediate, since the Thread you created was never alive, because you never started it.

Obviously changing `ex.execute(sleepTask)` to `sleepTask.start()` would get the `TERMINATED` state as you had expected, but I have a feeling that is not what you wanted to have done in the first place

Comment: can you also explain why the thread state as reported using Thread.getAllStackTraces.keySet() isTIMED_WAITING ?

Comment: It is not always `TIMED_WAITING` I got `WAITING` for example. The relevant docs are: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Comment: I am equally confused about seeing WAITING state :-(

Comment: So, the question would be, what would you expect it to be?

Comment: I suppose the thread's state is in waiting because after the current task is complete it is put back into threadpool waiting for the next callable to reuse (as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324030/java-thread-reuse ) ?