# I'm trying to make a program with 2 racers and it keeps giving me an IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, illegalstateexception

I have 2 threads and a main class in my program and whenever I try and run it, The one thread is giving me an IllegalThreadStateException and I'm not sure why. The program needs to make a tortoise and hare race, the tortoise can move 10 meters and never stop until he reaches 300 meters, and the hare can move 100 meters, but needs to rest 90% of the time. Following is my code, if anyone could help me out I would appreciate it. Additionally, when I did get it to run, the Hare thread is just outputting Hare: 0 a million times, so I'm not sure why that is happening either.

Main Class:

```
package runnerthread;

public class RunnerThread extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Get set...Go!");
        int hPosition = Hare.position;
        int tPosition = Tortoise.position;
        Thread hare = new Thread(new Hare());
        Thread tortoise = new Thread(new Tortoise());
        try{
       while(hPosition<300 && tPosition<300){
           tortoise.start();
           hare.start();
           Thread.sleep(300);
       }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
}
```

Tortoise thread:

```
public class Tortoise extends Thread {
    static int position;
    static int speed = 10;
    @Override
    public void run(){
            position = speed + 10;
        System.out.println("Tortoise: "+position);
    }
}
```

Hare thread:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Hare extends Thread{
     static int position;
    int speed = 100;
    int restingPercent = 90;
    Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt((100-1)+1) + 1;
    @Override
    public void run(){
    while(position<300){
    if (randomNum<=restingPercent){
        System.out.println("Hare: "+position);
    }else {
        position+=100;
        System.out.println("Hare: "+position);
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call start more than once on a thread.  Thread Objects cannot be reused. You can use a Runnable for that purpose. For more info check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324114/10632970