# Executor service: How it acts as watchdog for thread-pools?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to understand how `ExecutorService` acts as watchdog for the thread-pools that it creates.

Basically, as I understand, `ExecutorService` is just an object, it is not a "thread or process" which creates other threads.

Typically,for `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
// Now, requesting Executor Service to "execute" each submitted Tasks.
threadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable);
```

Likewise for `ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor`

```
scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(threadFactory);
scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 2000, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Essentially, they are **just objects**, how are they able to , for example, "restart a thread if it dies".

I am not able to understand this, for example, in case of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` we call method once for periodic action, after that , how that **object** is able to manage threads.

I did look into the code, I still have doubts as to how a **object** can manage all this? (creation of thread pools, submitting the Jobs to Queues, restarting threads in thread-pool and so on)

Comment: You may find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324030/java-thread-reuse).

Comment: @akuzminykh: My question isn't about reusing the thread pools, but how does it "manage", for example, if thread dies, then it has to create a new one? It's just an object, so how does it "sees" the dynamics . Reusing of thread is ok, it is more or less in each thread, it runs infinitely, and take Runnable Tasks from a queue.

Answer (score 2):

You should have better look into the code. Actually, most of the executors has a private nested class that encapsulate your *Runnable* and managed it inside the thread.

**Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor** just create a *ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor* with one thread. 
And then when you push a task, it creates a *ScheduledFutureTask* (also encapsulated in a *RunnableScheduledFuture*) and creates a thread **if** necessary.

[scheduleAtFixedRate](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor-source.html#line.384) :

```java
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                              long initialDelay,
                                              long period,
                                              TimeUnit unit) {
    ...
    RunnableScheduledFuture<?> t = decorateTask(command,
                                                new ScheduledFutureTask<Object>(command,
                                                                null,
                                                                triggerTime,
                                                                unit.toNanos(period)));
    delayedExecute(t);
    return t;
}
```

[delayedExecute](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor-source.html#line.216)

```java
private void delayedExecute(Runnable command) {
    if (isShutdown()) { // handling the cancellation 
        reject(command);
        return;
    }

    if (getPoolSize() < getCorePoolSize()) // increase number of thread if necessary
        prestartCoreThread();
    super.getQueue().add(command); // queue the task to be processed a soon as a task is finished
}
```

After been enqueued, the executor will unqueue one by one (in the case of a single thread executor, a thread pool with one thread), a *Thread* will eventually be created, also called workers in the code. And it will call the run() method of the previoussly enqueued task :

[ScheduledFutureTask.run](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor-source.html#line.205)

```java
public void run() {
    if (isPeriodic())
        runPeriodic();
    else
        ScheduledFutureTask.super.run(); // just call run() of your Runnable
}
```

Let's imagine that we previously submitted a task using **scheduleAtFixedRate**, the task will be considered as periodic and the method runPeriodic will be called :

[ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor-source.html#line.179)

```java
private void runPeriodic() {
    boolean ok = ScheduledFutureTask.super.runAndReset(); // call run() from your Runnable
    boolean down = isShutdown();
    // Reschedule if not cancelled and not shutdown or policy allows
    if (ok && (!down ||
           (getContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy() && !isTerminating()))) {
        long p = period;
        if (p > 0)
            time += p;
        else
            time = now() - p;
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.super.getQueue().add((Runnable) this);
    }
    // This might have been the final executed delayed
    // task.  Wake up threads to check.
    else if (down)
        interruptIdleWorkers();
}
```

This gives you an idea about how the magic happen. Most of the 'watchdog's' job happens inside the thread, they manage themselves. The job of the executor is to ensure that it's queue is always empty and dispatch and creates tasks over the threads.
The behavior of tasks is then handled by themselves by accessing the Executor directly, thanks of the nested class possibility of Java.